# Equivalence of Lebesgue-Integral definitions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to show the equivalence of two definitions of the Lebesgue-integral for functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$.

The first book (Königsberger, Analysis 2, Springer) defines a semi-norm for a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{∞\}$ by setting $\Vert f\Vert_1 = \inf\{I(\phi) : |f(x)|≤\phi(x)\}∈\mathbb{R}_0^+\cup\{\infty\}$ where $\phi$ is a infinite sum

$$
\phi = \sum_{k=1}^∞ c_k \mathbb{1}_{Q_k},
$$

the $Q_i$ are open cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $c_i≥ 0$ and $I(\phi)$ is the canonic extension of the definition of an integral for a step function. Now we say that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if there exists a sequence of step functions $(\phi_n)_n$ such that $\Vert f-\phi_n\Vert_1 \to 0$ when $n\to∞$. In this case you define $$∫ f := \lim ∫\phi_n.$$

The other book (A. Weir, Lebesgue Integration and Measure, CUP) also defines an integral $I(\phi)$ for step functions and says that a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ belongs to $L^+$ if there exists an increasing sequence $(\phi)_n$ of step functions converging to $f$ almost everywhere (so null sets are already defined without a measure by covering the set with bounded intervals so that the total length of these intervals is as small as you like) so that the sequence $(∫\phi_n)_n$ of integrals converges and then you set $$∫ f := \lim \int \phi_n.$$ Then a function $h\colon\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be Lebesgue integrable if it is the difference of two functions $a,b∈L^+$, i.e. $h=a-b$, and then you have the definition $∫ h= ∫ a-∫ b$.

My question is if you know how to show the equivalence of these two approaches to the Lebesgue integral or if you know some literture where I can find a proof.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

well ... you need to establish that any function that is Lebesgue integrable according to one definition is also Lebesgue integrable according to the other definition. Here's a high-level sketch of the proof:

**1. From Königsberger's Definition to Weir's Definition:**

Let $ f: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\} $ be Lebesgue integrable according to Königsberger's definition. This means there exists a sequence of step functions $ \{\phi_n\} $ such that $ \|f - \phi_n\|_1 \rightarrow 0 $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $.

Define $ a_n = \inf\{I(\psi) : |f(x)| \leq \psi, \psi \text{ is a step function}\} $, and let $ \{a_n\} $ be the corresponding sequence of integrals.

Construct an increasing sequence of step functions $ \{\psi_n\} $ such that $a_n \leq I(\psi_n) \leq a_{n+1} $ for all $ n $. This can be achieved by considering simple step functions that approximate $ f $ from below.

Now, according to Weir's definition, $ f $ is Lebesgue integrable, and $ \int f = \lim \int \psi_n $.

**2. From Weir's Definition to Königsberger's Definition:**

Assume $ f $ is Lebesgue integrable according to Weir's definition, i.e., there exist $ a, b \in L^+ $ such that $ f = a - b $. Let $ \{\phi_n\} $ be an increasing sequence of step functions converging to $ a $ almost everywhere. Similarly, let $ \{\psi_n\} $ be an increasing sequence of step functions converging to $ b $ almost everywhere.

Construct a sequence of step functions $ \{\chi_n\} $ by setting $ \chi_n = \phi_n + \psi_n $. Note that $ |\chi_n| \leq \phi_n + \psi_n \leq a + b $ for all $ n $.

According to Königsberger's definition, $ \|f - \chi_n\|_1 \rightarrow 0 $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will think about your comment in detail tomorrow. But I tried to prove the statement 2 in your post for a while. Do you mean $\chi_n=\phi_n-\psi_n$? - because then we know that $\chi_n$ converges to $f$ a.e. But then I don't see why this convergence implies that $\chi_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L^1$-semi-norm. What I definitly know is, that pointwise convergence doesn't imply convergence in the $L^1$-semi-norm and vice-versa.

Comment: @RobRTex Given $f = a - b$ with $a, b \in L^+$, we show $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (Königsberger sense) by constructing $\{\chi_n\}$ where $c_n$ is the infimum of step functions bounding $|f|$. These step functions ensure $c_n \leq I(\chi_n) \leq c_{n+1}$, and $\|\chi_n - f\|_1 \rightarrow 0$. The construction adapts to specifics of $a$, $b$, and Lebesgue integrability conditions. Adjust based on how step functions approximate $a$ and $b$.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thank you! I am thinking for hours now but I don't really know what you mean. When $c_n:=\inf\{I(\alpha):|f(x)|≤\alpha\}$ ($\alpha$ step function) I don't know what is the index $n$ for. The only thing I see is, that $c_n≤I(\chi_n)$ for any step-function $\chi_n$ bounding $|f|$. Thank you for your patience!